# ASP MVC Cookies Not Setting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have the following code:

```
//Cookie Object
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("Test");
myCookie["Username"] = "username";
myCookie["Role"] = "role";
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(24);

if (Request.Cookies["Test"] == null)
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
else
{
    HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Set(myCookie);
}
```

This is working fine on my local, but not on live. I've made sure the latest code is on live and everything. I've look at everything but can't figure out why. Any ideas?